# Falta la traducción del artículo "What is Flair?" del Centro de Ayuda

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

En https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/flair tenemos un nuevo artículo del Centro de Ayuda: *What is Flair?*

[g3rv4 lo ha añadido al repositorio](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages/issues/31) GitHub donde podemos ir subiendo traducciones, de modo que pego aquí abajo el texto original en inglés para que entre todos encontremos la mejor traducción y, finalmente, hagamos una pull request para subirlo a la web.

¿Alguien se anima?

Nótese que 'flair' se tradujo previamente como *miniperfil*.

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de añadir una captura que muestre la localización detallada del miniperfil, a prueba de despistados :P

Comment: Fantástico, mil gracias @lois6b :) Se me ocurrió que podríamos buscar un vídeo de YouTube más acorde con nuestra comunidad para el tema de la coña.

Comment: si,al menos en español

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traducción:

## ¿Qué es el miniperfil?

El miniperfil es una imagen que recoge tus logros (tu reputación, tus medallas, los sitios donde más has participado), perfecta para mostrarse en tu propia página web o imprimirla y hacerte un pin con ella [si eso es lo que prefieres](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtrLKGZZFg).

#### Ejemplo:

[image]

Para más información, ingresa en el sitio y visita la sección Miniperfil en [la página de ajustes de tu perfil](/users/edit/current) (Configuración > Configuración del sitio > Miniperfil).

[image]

---

Texto en inglés:

## What is Flair?

Flair is an image summarizing your accomplishments (your reputation, your badges, the top sites you've participated on), suitable for display on your own website or printing out and pinning to a vest [if that's what you prefer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtrLKGZZFg).

#### Example:

[image]

For more information, log in and visit the Flair section of [your profile's Site Settings](/users/edit/current).